# Automatically run new instance of my web application when user buy new license

Tags: java, architecture, saas, software-distribution

My question is how can I run a new instance of my java web application every time someone buy a new license or when someone wants to try on the application. What technologies are involved in this kind of functionality.

For example, the links bellow user can try the software and even make your domain to activate his instance of the software. The interesting thing is that every new version of the product all customers are automatically update.

https://www.thoughtworks.com/mingle/signup/
https://www.atlassian.com/ondemand/signup/form?product=jira-software.ondemand

Thanks you all;

Comment: Build your application as SaaS and Multitenant. Its not about particular technology.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done with virtualization and/or cloud based technologies.  In JIRA's case, they have shared how they went about implementing here:http://www.slideshare.net/GoAtlassian/inside-the-atlassian-ondemand-private-cloud Thoughtworks (Mingle) shared here: https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/how-we-moved-cloud.

There are lots of examples out there, but basically it is driven by scripted setups, cloud-based architectures, and lots of planning/design.

Comment: Wow, perfect. Those link give me lots of ideias and guide me to correct path. Thanks!